# Global state with IORef, why doesn't this work?

Tags: haskell

For the sake of understanding I played around with IORef and tried to come up with something that would be close to having a global, mutable state:

```
import Data.IORef

x :: IO (IORef Int)
x = newIORef 0

incrAndPrint :: IO ()
incrAndPrint = do z <- x
                  modifyIORef z (+1)
                  readIORef z >>= putStrLn . show

main :: IO ()
main = incrAndPrint >> incrAndPrint
```

However, to my surprise this prints

```
1
1
```

not

```
1
2
```

Could someone explain why?
Moreover, is there a way to make this 'work'? If not, why?

Comment: Mutable, yes. Global, no.

Comment: Global mutability is _very_ hard to arrange.  (Deliberately so, and it's a good thing too.)

Comment: Haskell is referentially transparent, meaning that after you define `x = e` you can always replace `x` with `e` anywhere. Hence, your `incrAndPrint` is equivalent to `do z <- newIORef 0 ; modifyIORef z (+1) ; ...`, hence the final `incrAndPrint >> incrAndPrint` actually runs `newIORef`  twice, creating two independent references. So, `1 1` is the output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `x` is an `IO` action that creates a new `IORef Int` so when you use it it will always create a new one starting at `0`.
You can easily make this work by increment the same reference both times:

```hs
incrAndPrint :: IORef Int -> IO ()
incrAndPrint z = do
    modifyIORef z (+1)
    readIORef z >>= print

main = do
    z <- x
    incrAndPrint z
    incrAndPrint z
```

If you really, ***really*** have to use a global mutable state you can do it with
`unsafePerformIO`, which works with GHC because it will make sure the `IORef` isn't
accessed before it's initialized and the `NOINLINE` prevents a new reference to be
created wherever you use it.

```hs
import Data.IORef
import System.IO.Unsafe

x :: IORef Int
x = unsafePerformIO $ newIORef 0
{-# NOINLINE x #-}

incrAndPrint :: IO ()
incrAndPrint = do
    modifyIORef x (+1)
    readIORef x >>= putStrLn . show

main :: IO ()
main = incrAndPrint >> incrAndPrint
```